# Removal of Class object key from Map in Java

Tags: java, object, collections

I have a Map with a key/value pair made up of a string and class object `Block`. The `remove(Object key, Object value)` method fails to actually remove the object specified.

`private static Map<String, ArrayList<Block>> stockInfo = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

> > My IDE tips me off that my entry in the `Object value` data field "*may not contain values of type 'Block'* " What fundamental concept am I missing about Java and passing values in methods? I have only been coding in Java for a short period.

`stockInfo.remove(symbolCode, (stockInfo.get(symbolCode)).get(0));`

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Map with a key/value pair made up of a string and class object Block.

No, you don’t.

You declared a mapping of `String` to a *collection* of objects of type `Block`. Specifically an `ArrayList` collection.

So the compiler refuses your attempt to remove a string-to-block entry because there are no such entries. You have only string-to-list-of-blocks entries in your `Map`.

> `Map<String, ArrayList<Block>> stockInfo = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

A mapping of string to block would look like this:

```
Map< String, Block >
```

Comment: You are correct, but my `remove()` method is trying to delete a `Map< String, Block >` is it not?

Comment: Or are you saying that my attempt to modify part of a maps value is inherently impossible?

Comment: @Mithrandir The issue is a *single* `Block` object versus a *list* of `Block` objects.